# Send an email with Javascript (Not a form)

Tags: javascript, email

I can't put the code in here since the information is security sensitive, but I will try my best to explain.

I have a local server with a javascript/html web based app that detects security alarms. I want to take an alarm that is received (I already have it turned into a string such as "Input 1 Zone 8 has been triggered") and send the alert to a phone.

For example, I get the alarm, and then send the string to 123-456-7535@txt.att.net

It isn't a form which is all I've been able to find support on.

Comment: You can't send mail directly from code in a web browser, but it's really not clear if that's what you're asking. Also it doesn't much matter whether there's a form involved; you need some server-side code to send the mail, and exactly how you do that depends on the server-side framework in use (and other things).

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/?src=so), which allows sending email from the client side Javascript code using pre-built templates [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to send a request (API call) to backend, which will process your request and send a mail. You cannot send the mail from frontend because doing so will expose your email service credentials to the client or user. You will have to use a service like `sendgrid` to send mails. You'll find plenty of documentation on their websites as well on blogs. Stackoverflow is not for such guide based questions but rather for specific issues that you are not able to resolve after putting much effort